# Unable to connect to SQL Server Linux Docker container via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I'm quite new to Linux OS's so hope this isn't a stupid question!!

**Software:**
Windows 10 Pro
Docker for Windows (1.13.0-beta38 (9805))
SQL Server Management Studio v17.0 RC1

**Issue:**
I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server Linux container using SSMS.  It's not worked, so looking over the documentation it seems you need [SQL Server Tools installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker) (bottom of page) on top of of the SQL Server Linux image.

I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu) to install SQL Server Tools on Ubuntu (base image of SQL Server Linux Image)

**Error:**
`bash: curl: command not found`

**Steps to reproduce error:**

- Pull latest `microsoft/sql-server-linux` image
- Run according to instructions:  `docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux`
- Attach to container using:  `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`
- Attempt to import public repository GPG keys:  `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

**Thing's I've tried:**

- I've tried running `apt-get install curl` but all i get is `E: Unable to locate package curl`
- Googling - to no end

**First edit - Connecting via SSMS**
I've tried connecting to the container from SSMS using the following server names (I am using SQL authentication with the credentials specified during the `docker run` command):

- localhost:1433
- localhost\[container_name]
- [container_ip_address]:1433

**Solution (kind of)**
OK so i got this working.  But I'm not 100% sure what did the trick.
I used `localhost` as the server name (defaults to port 1433)
I also mounted a volume to the container as part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes: 
  - C:\local\volume\path:/var/opt/mssql
```

**SQL Server Linux Logs**

```
Configuring Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)...
Configuration complete.
This is an evaluation version.  There are [141] days left in the evaluation period.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.39 Server      Microsoft SQL Server vNext (CTP1.1) - 14.0.100.187 (X64)
        Dec 10 2016 02:51:11
        Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
        on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)
2017-01-23 08:14:10.40 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2017-01-23 08:14:10.41 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.41 Server      All rights reserved.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.42 Server      Server process ID is 4116.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.42 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\var\opt\mssql\log\errorlog'.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.42 Server      Registry startup parameters:
         -d C:\var\opt\mssql\data\master.mdf
         -l C:\var\opt\mssql\data\mastlog.ldf
         -e C:\var\opt\mssql\log\errorlog
2017-01-23 08:14:10.44 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 2 cores per socket and 2 logical processors per socket, 2 total logical processors; using 2 logical
processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.45 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.46 Server      Detected 3143 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.46 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.54 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2017-01-23 08:14:10.68 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.79 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.79 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.84 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2017-01-23 08:14:10.84 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This message provides a description o
f the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.86 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational m
essage only.  No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.87 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initial
ization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.89 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1,
2017-01-23 08:14:10.89 spid5s      Starting up database 'master'.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.91 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2017-01-23 08:14:10.98 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.04 spid5s      8 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.07 spid5s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.08 spid5s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.13 spid5s      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.13 spid5s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.13 spid5s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.14 spid5s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.18 spid5s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2017-01-23 08:14:11.20 spid5s      Server name is '65507453cf5a'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.23 spid17s     Password policy update was successful.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.24 spid5s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.24 spid6s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.26 spid6s      The resource database build version is 14.00.100. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.29 spid6s      Starting up database 'model'.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.61 spid5s      7 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.61 spid6s      7 transactions rolled forward in database 'model' (3:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.63 spid6s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'model' (3:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.63 spid5s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.63 spid6s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'model' (3). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.64 spid5s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'msdb' (4). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.75 spid6s      Polybase feature disabled.
2017-01-23 08:14:11.76 spid6s      Clearing tempdb database.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.10 spid17s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.11 spid17s     Server is listening on [ 0.0.0.0 <ipv4> 1433].
2017-01-23 08:14:12.13 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
2017-01-23 08:14:12.13 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.14 spid17s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.40 spid6s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.68 spid6s      The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
2017-01-23 08:14:12.69 spid20s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.70 spid20s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.71 spid20s     Service Broker manager has started.
2017-01-23 08:14:12.75 spid5s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:14:15.89 spid29s     The activated proc '[dbo].[sp_syspolicy_events_reader]' running on queue 'msdb.dbo.syspolicy_event_queue' output the following:  'Trans
action (Process ID 29) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.'
2017-01-23 08:19:14.95 spid51      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2017-01-23 08:19:18.62 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-01-23 08:19:18.65 spid51      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2016.140.100' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no u
ser action is required.
```

Comment: What server name you are entering in SSMS?

Comment: You do not need SQL Server Tools installed on the container to connect from the outside. You have some other issue.

Comment: Are you running the Linux host in a virtual machine? Also please attach the output from `docker logs #containerHash`

Comment: Hi Peter, yes it's running on the default virtual machine that Docker for Windows creates. I've updated the question with the logs.

Comment: SSMS uses a comma rather than a colon to delimit between server name and port number. Try `localhost,1433`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the comment from Ed Harper resolved my issue:

> SSMS uses a comma rather than a colon to delimit between server name
>   and port number. Try localhost,1433. – Ed Harper Jan 23 at 12:52

The server name field in SMSS required a format of locahost,[dockerport].
So in my case I needed:

localhost,32768